# Creating Variables via A loop in r

Tags: r

I am using the following code to download the YTD AdjClose of SPY.

```
library(tseries)
AjdClose_SPY <- get.hist.quote("SPY", quote="Adj", start="2015-01-01", retclass="zoo")
```

Now, say I have a portfolio

```
portfolio <- c('SPY','AAPL','HD')
```

How would I be able to loop through "portfolio" and create a variable "AdjClose_" for each ticker in my portfolio? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just try `setNames(lapply(portfolio, function(x) get.hist.quote(x, quote="Adj", start="2015-01-01", retclass="zoo")),paste0("AjdClose_",portfolio))`. You'll get a `list` object whose names are what you indicated. Don't create several variables; a single named list is much cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: or maybe: `setNames(do.call(merge, lapply(portfolio, get.hist.quote, quote="Adj", start="2015-01-01", retclass="zoo")), portfolio)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the `quantmod` package? Example:

```
library(quantmod)
portfolio <- c('SPY','AAPL','HD')
getSymbols(portfolio, start = "2015-01-01")
```

This will create xts objects for each ticker in `portfolio` in your current environment that hold "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", and "Adjusted" price data for each ticker.

If you then want, you can put all Adjusted prices in a data frame like so:

```
AdjPrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(portfolio, function(x) Ad(get(x))))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I am utterly confused though, how the heck did: "AdjPrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(portfolio, function(x) Ad(get(x))))" know to take the adjusted close?

Comment: `lapply` cycles through all character strings in `portfolio` and applies `Ad(get(x))` to them. The quantmod function `Ad()` extracts the Adjusted Close and `get(x)` calls an R object using a character string. `do.call(merge,...)` then merges all list items from `lapply()` into a single data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Check ?assign

Example:

```
stock = "AAPL"
assign(paste0("AdjClose_", stock), 100)
```